# Extract characters in URL after certain character up to certain character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract certain piece of a URL using regex (JavaScript) and having trouble excluding characters after a certain piece.  Here's what I have so far:

URL: http://www.somesite.com/state-de

Using `url.match(/\/[^\/]+$/)[0]` I can extract the state-de like I want.

However when the URL becomes  http://www.somesite.com/state-de?page=r and I do the same regex it pulls everything including the "?page=r" which I don't want.  I want to only extract the state-de regardless of whats after it (looks like usually a "?" follows it)

Comment: `\/([^\/]+?)\?.*$`  https://regex101.com/r/oB2dC4/1

Comment: Sorry it isn't always "/state-de" that I want to extract, sometimes its other information but i do always want to cut off the "?page=a" part that may or may not follow.

Comment: so you want the text after the last forward slash to the question mark. It's helpful in these sorts of questions to show a couple expected inputs and outputs. Edit your question to convey this information. It isn't at all clear what you want. You have five answers and you've provided minimal information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend reading up on regular expressions in general. What you want to do here is make the regular expression stop when it hits the ? in the URL.

Using capturing groups to select which part of the match that you want might also be useful here.

Example:

```
url.match(/(\/[^\/?]+)(?:\?.*)?$/)[1]
```

Comment: Unnecessary use of capturing groups.

Comment: @MarkII reason why i posted a lookahead based regex means, your regex won't return `state-de` it does return `/state-de`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm sort of confused by the positive lookahead in your post. Trying it out in a console I only get the match of "/". Did you mean something like s.match(/\/[^\/?]+(?=\?|$)/)[0]

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
var arr = url.split("/")
arr[arr.length - 1].split("?")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want do it by regex try this one:

`url.match(/https?:\/\/([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z]+\/([a-z0-9_-])\/?(\?.*)?/)[1]`

Or you could do it using JQuery:

```
var url = 'http://www.somesite.com/state-de?page=r#mark4';

// Create a special anchor element, set the URL to it

var a = $('<a>', { href:url } )[1];

console.log(a.hostname);
console.log(a.pathname);
console.log(a.search);
console.log(a.hash);
```

Comment: not sure what yours is trying to match, my test run has it extracting 'somesite' which isn't what i need

Comment: Sorry, there is another index of the match you need – `[1]`. Second pair of parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid overly complex RegExs when possible, so I tend to do this in multiple steps (with `.replace()`):

```
var stripped = url.replace(/[?#].*/, ''); // Strips anything after ? or #
```

You can now do the simpler transform to get the state, e.g.:

```
var state = stripped.split('/').pop()
```